# How do I make a div click-through through another div? (navigation bar)

Tags: html, click

website: www.vocabularybuilder.co

I want the logo and the navigation to be clickable, it used to work but i did something and now it doesn't :/

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add z-index: 1 and position: relative for this class.

```
.site-header__logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto !important;
    max-width: 400px;
    font-size: 1.85714em;
    top: 0;
    height: 90px;
    display: table;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
.nav-bar {
    pointer-events:none;
}
// for the 2 links
li a {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Hope it'll work. This was already answered here [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements). ctto